# jQuery: If the selected element $(this) has a parent with a classname of 'last'

Tags: jquery, dom, traversal, tree-traversal

I must be missing something quite important, I have been using .parent().parent().parent().. etc to traverse down the DOM and .next().next() to traverse up the DOM.

I know this is wrong and that I need something more reliable, I need a selector that will traverse from the clicked element $(this) down the DOM to see if the element clicked is within an element with a class of "last".

```
div.last > div > table > tr > td > a[THE ITEM CLICKED is in the element last]
```

and

```
div > div > table > tr > td > a[THE ITEM CLICKED is not in the element last]
```

then if the result has length

```
var isWithinLastRow = [amazingSelector].length;
```

do something else in this case.

Comment: Try `$(this).closest('div.last')` Also.. `.parent()` and `.next()` are not the related(meaning not exact opposite). `.next()` is to fetch the next sibling and `.parent` is to go straight to the parent. The exact opposite of `.next` is `.prev`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Try this out:-http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/PjSV7/

**HTML:-**

```
<div class="last">
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a>Test</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a>Test</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:-**

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("a").on("click",function(){
       if($(this).closest(".last").length>0)
       {
           alert("Clicked anchor with div parent class as last");
       }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 10):

Your question is a little hard to understand. You want to check if the element clicked has an ancestor element with the class `last`, yes?

If so, you can do so with [`$.fn.parents`](http://api.jquery.com/parents):

```
if ($(this).parents('.last').length) {
    // element has an ancestor element with the class "last"
}
```

Comment: From the comparison between `parents` and `closest` in the [latter's API](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) it looks like `closest` is faster because it stops at the first match.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this -

```
if($(this).closest(".last").length > 0) {
   alert("it's inside");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/#entry-longdesc)

```
var isWithLastRow = $(this).closest('div.last').length
```